# Craft raw wifi packet

Tags: python, wifi, packet

I'd like to craft single wifi packets, getting the raw binary data just before they are converted to a waveform and transmitted. As I understand it, this should be at the data link layer, and include all the headers (sync bits, CRC, etc) and the data itself. Is there a way to do this (preferably with Python)? I've looked into scapy, Wireshark, etc but I can't tell if or how they can get me what I need.

Comment: Can you get little more info? Because ScaPy can manipulate packets, send them, capture them, and match requests and replies.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry – I'd really like to take arbitrary data (say an HTTP request) and package it up with the sync bits, all the headers, CRC, etc and get a sequence of bits that matches the packet just before conversion to a waveform. It seems Wireshark, etc can give me a packet, but a few layers up. I want to see it at that very last step.

Answer (score 1):

You can dump all packet via monitor mode.
For example, this code sniffing all data packets from mon0 interface:

```
from scapy.all import *

def handler(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
    if pkt.type == 2:
            pkt.show()

sniff(iface="mon0", prn=handler)
```

Comment: – this is very close to what I need, but is there a way to make a packet *from* some data instead of sniffing real-world packets? Basically, have scapy add all the appropriate headers?

Comment: See this example: [Sending 802.11 Packets with Scapy](http://blog.packetheader.net/2014/01/sending-80211-packets-with-scapy.html) and [ScaPy usage](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, that link is promising but I'm not getting results that look right – I'm not seeing the sync bits or other header pieces I would expect.

Comment: Ex for the DNS query:
```[*] DNS query www.google.com (A) -> 10.10.10.2?
0000   00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0010   00 00 00 00 DE AD BE EF  00 11 22 33 44 55 00 00   .........."3DU..
0020   AA AA 03 00 00 00 08 00  45 00 00 3C 00 01 00 00   ........E..<....
0030   40 11 52 91 0A 0A 0A 0A  0A 0A 0A 02 D5 7C 00 35   @.R..........|.5
0040   00 28 74 25 00 00 00 00  00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00   .(t%............
0050   03 77 77 77 06 67 6F 6F  67 6C 65 03 63 6F 6D 00   .www.google.com.
0060   00 01 00 01                                        ....```